# How to put a variable in x/y label using matplotlib module pyplot

Tags: python, label, matplotlib, python-3.2

I am generating a stacked bar graph in Python3.2  and using  'Matplotlib' module 'pyplot'. The only problem is that in the 'xlabel' I have to include a variable (integer) for number of entries analyzed. I have tried a lot but could not find the way of including the variable in xlabel.

Part of my code:

```
plt.ylabel('Percentage', fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(size=10))
plt.xlabel('position', fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(size=10))
plt.title("'Graph-A",fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(size=10))

plt.xticks(np.arange(22), np.arange(1,23), fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(size=8))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,121,5), fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(size=8))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0], p4[0],p5[0]), ('A','B','C','D','E'), loc=1, prop=font_manager.FontProperties(size=7))
```

The variable 'entries' hold the value of entries processed and I need to include this value in xlabel. Please help?

AK

Comment: Just to be clear you want to pass a variable into the `plt.xlabel`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I got you right, you could try:

```
plt.xlabel('position %d' % entries, fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(size=10))
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't thought that it will work and that's why didn't tested.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you can do in python 3.6.

`plt.xlabel('Your variable is put here: {}'.format(variable))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It worked for me.

```
plt.xlabel('position'+str(entries), fontproperties=font_manager.FontProperties(size=10))
```

I have used it in my code as

```
plt.plot(qtime,hy_p,'r.')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Hz at node '+str(50))
```